# "IndexError: list index out of range" trying to make names possessive

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm attempting to make it so that when someone enters their name, the program will add `"(name)'s"` if it does not end in an `s`, and `"(name)'"` if it does:

```
name = list(input("What is your name?"))
name2 = int(len(name))

if name[name2] == "s":
    name[name2] = "s'" 
else:
    name[name2] = name(name2) , "'s"
print("".join(name))
```

Error code below:

```
What is your name?James
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\Python\lists i guess.py", line 5, in <module>
    if name[name2] == "s":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

end of error code.

By the way when I changed `" () "` out for `" [] "` on

```
if name[name2] == "s":
    name[name2] = "s'"
```

It seemed to stop showing a different error code which was `'cannot assign function'`, could someone please explain why?

Answer (score 3):

Python lists are indexed *starting at 0*. That means that the *last* element in a list always has the index `len(listobject) - 1`.

You are trying to use `len(listobject)` so you are trying to access an index that can never be in the list.

Just use `-1` as the index instead. Negative indices count from the end, with `-1` being the last element, `-2` the second last, etc.

Also, strings are already sequences, you don't need to convert these to a list to test for elements. Just use *concatenation* to add additional text to the end; `name + "'"` or `name + "'s"`.

The following would work to add `"'s"` or `"'"` to the end:

```
name = input("What is your name?")

if name[-1] == 's':
    name += "'"  # only add an apostrophe
else:
    name += "'s"

print(name)
```

Don't confuse [calling an object with `(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) with [subscription with `[...]`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions); getting specific elements out of a sequence is done with subscription, while making a function do something and return a result is done with calling.

Because you can't assign to the result of a function call, the expression `name(name2)` can't be used as a target for a `=` assignment, which is why you got your error. But you *can* assign to a specific element of a list, which is why `name[name2] = <something>` *does* work.

Comment: Or just `name += "'" if name[-1] == "s" else "'s"` but I guess that may be a little unreadable for those new to Python...

Comment: @PM2Ring: Yeah, I tend not to use a conditional expression in such cases as it can hurt readability.

Answer (score 1):

You make some wrong assumptions on how strings work in Python.

You are getting an `IndexError` because Python uses zero-based indexing for its iterables, so `some_list[len(some_list)]` will always return an `IndexError`.

Even if it did work, `name[name2] = name(name2) , "'s"` wasn't going to do what you expected it to do.

Here is the corrected code using your approach:

```
name = list(input("What is your name?"))
name2 = int(len(name))

if name[name2 - 1] == "s":
    name[name2 - 1] = "s'" 
else:
    name[name2 - 1] = name[name2 - 1] + "'s"
print("".join(name))
```

But here is another, more Pythonic way, without turning the string to a list of characters:

```
name = input("What is your name?")

if name.endswith("s"):
    name += "'" 
else:
    name += "'s"
print(name)
```